# VBA: Copying a chart in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

What's the difference between these three snippets of code? Only 3) works and I don't get why.

```
wbInd.Sheets("EuropeCovBonds graph fix").ChartObjects("Diagramm 1").Copy
```

-> Error 1004: The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type

```
wbInd.Sheets("EuropeCovBonds graph fix").ChartObjects("Diagramm 1").ChartArea.Copy
```

-> Error 438: Object doesn't support property or method

```
wbInd.Sheets("EuropeCovBonds graph fix").ChartObjects("Diagramm 1").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
```

This one works. I made it with the macro recorder.

Comment: When reproducing your problem, I am not getting an error on your first line `wbInd.Sheets("EuropeCovBonds graph fix").ChartObjects("Diagramm 1").Copy`. This in fact works fine and is how I would do it. Is the chart on a ChartSheet, or is it on a 'normal' sheet. Is there any additional information you can give?

Comment: Normal sheet. `wbInd.Sheets()` works fine for others, I use it a bunch of times. On the sheet, there are two charts ("Diagramm 1" and "Diagramm 2"). I don't know what additional info to give you, what could cause this problem?

Comment: If you open the Immediate-window add `Debug.Print wbInd.Sheets("EuropeCovBonds graph fix").ChartObjects("Diagramm 1").Type`, what do you get?
The reason for asking is that it seems you are unable to do it for that **chart type**, and I don't know what kind of chart you are trying to copy

Comment: Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: My bad, I meant to write `Debug.Print wbInd.Sheets("EuropeCovBonds graph fix").ChartObjects("Diagramm 1").Chart.Type` Try that?

Comment: In a simple example here, I can do 1 and 3 successfully, and for 2 you need to insert Chart between ChartObjects and ChartArea: `wbInd.Sheets("EuropeCovBonds graph fix").ChartObjects("Diagramm 1").Chart.ChartArea.Copy`. What gets copied in all three cases is the same.

Comment: @Prebsus Sorry, I was just about to leave work when you wrote your last comment. I tried it with your line, which returned -4169, and also tried `.Chart.ChartType`,which gave me 73. 

Right clicking on the chart tells me it's a line chart

Comment: Yeah, so -4169 is a Scatter plot and 73 is a Scatter with Smoothed Lines and No Data Markers (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcharttype for more info on chart types). Based on the information you've shared here I have not been able to reproduce the problem, and I agree with @JonPeltier assesment. If you want to share your excel-book I can try to have a look at that, but outside of that I'm afraid I don't know what would help...